# OneSignal REST API get segment count

Tags: rest, filter, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

Having read the REST API [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference), I couldn't find any information related to getting the segment count for a notification. Is it possible to get it using the REST API? Getting the segment count is possible in OneSignal developer panel as you can change the filters and see the estimated number of clients who receive your notification. But I want to get that estimated number using the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the estimated receiving users before creating the notification using the REST API. A workaround to this would be creating templates and using the template_id in the API call.